# How to find the intersecting area of two sub images using OpenCv?

Tags: python, opencv

Let's say there are two sub images of a large image. I am trying to detect the overlapping area of two sub images. I know that template matching can help to find the templates. But i'm not sure how to find the intersected area and remove them in either one of the sub images. Please help me out.

Comment: Assuming you have two masks (one of each sub image), you can `cv2.bitwise_and()` the two masks together to obtain only overlapping/intersecting areas between the two masks.

Answer (score 1):

MatchTemplate returns the most probable position of a template inside a picture. You could do the following steps:

- Find the (x,y) origin, width and height of each picture inside the larger one
- Save them as rectangles with that data(cv::Rect r1, cv::Rect r2)
- Using the & operator, find the overlap area between both rectangles (r1&r2)

Answer (score 0):

Extract features from both images using feature descriptor (SIFT, SURF, ORB, Daisy, etc). Then you match those keypoints and ran RANSAC to estimate homography matrix.

[Here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/) is a nice post with code.